# UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer is triggering multiple times

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I'm using the following code for going back and forward in my WebView with `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer`:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet var homewebview: UIWebView!

        // create left edge and right edge gesture
        let leftEdgePanGesture = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer()
        let rightEdgePanGesture = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer()


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            // add target for gesture
            self.leftEdgePanGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(FirstViewController.handleLeftEdge(_:)))
            self.rightEdgePanGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(FirstViewController.handleRightEdge(_:)))

            // set detection edge
            self.leftEdgePanGesture.edges = UIRectEdge.Left
            self.rightEdgePanGesture.edges = UIRectEdge.Right

            // add gesture into view
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.leftEdgePanGesture)
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.rightEdgePanGesture)
        }
        func handleLeftEdge( gesture: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer ) {
            homewebview.goBack()
        }

        // perform operation when right edge gesture detected
        func handleRightEdge( gesture: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer ) {
            homewebview.goForward()
        }
    }
```

My problem is that it's triggering multiple times. It doesn't go back/forward one webpage, it goes back/forward ca. 5 webpages.

Is there any solution? Or will I have to use `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`. I rather don't want to use `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` because it doesn't react as reliable as `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer`. `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` sometimes "thinks" I want to scroll vertically in my WebView and doesn't react. Or is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pan gesture recognizer calls the handler method any time its state changes. That includes when it starts, ends, and every movement in between. Inside the handler, you need to check the gesture recognizer's state and decide what to do.

You want to trigger your code only once per gesture, and you want to do it only when the touch has moved more than a threshold amount.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let leftEdgePanGesture = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer()
    var leftPanTriggered: Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        leftEdgePanGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLeftEdge(_:)))
        leftEdgePanGesture.edges = .Left
        view.addGestureRecognizer(leftEdgePanGesture)
    }

    func handleLeftEdge(gesture: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer) {
        switch gesture.state {
            case .Began, .Changed:
                if !leftPanTriggered {
                    let threshold: CGFloat = 10  // you decide this
                    let translation = abs(gesture.translationInView(view).x)
                    if translation >= threshold  {
                        performLeftGesture()
                        leftPanTriggered = true
                    }
                }

            case .Ended, .Failed, .Cancelled:
                leftPanTriggered = false

            default: break
        }
    }

    func performLeftGesture() {
        homewebview.goBack()
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Kurt Revis, I added it for left and right. Left works but right doesn't work. Why that? Shall I provide the code?

Comment: When swiping right the translation would be negative. Use `abs(gesture.translationInView(view).x)` to compare against the threshold. Edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working now. BTW: What does "CGFloat" mean?

Comment: It's the floating-point type used for geometry values in CoreGraphics (and the frameworks that are built on top of CoreGraphics, like UIKit). It's either a  Float or Double depending on whether you're using 32-bit or 64-bit code. Google can tell you a lot more.

Comment: What will happen when I set the digit in `let threshold: CGFloat = 1` higher or lower?